# downloding csv file is not working in internet explorer11 it redirecting page into another page (web page cann't be displayed)

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is not downloading csv file, it redirecting current page to another page (web page cann't be displayed)

This is code for downloading csv file

```
var fileName = "test";
var data = $(this).first(); //Only one table
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + escape(data);
a.download = fileName;
a.style = 'display:none';

if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
    var blob = new Blob([data], {
        "type": "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
    });
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
}
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

If I debug this code it ask for downloading a file after that go to the another page
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You had special handling for IE browser.

But you need to put non-IE code in `else` block.

```
var fileName = "test";
var data = $(this).first(); //Only one table
var mimeType = 'text/csv';
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + escape(data);
a.download = fileName;
a.style = 'display:none';

if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
    var blob = new Blob([data], {
        "type": "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
    });
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
}
else { // ELSE non-IE
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can also do like this,we can add a return statement,this looks better

```
var fileName = "test";
var data = $(this).first(); //Only one table
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + escape(data);
a.download = fileName;
a.style = 'display:none';

if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
    var blob = new Blob([data], {
        "type": "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
    });
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
   return;
}
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```